# faster way to counting and printing subsequences in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sequence, mathematical-optimization, sequences

I have a big list of IDs (my_list) which is of variable size. I want to count all possible sub-sequences of length 3 from this list and print the sub-sequences along with its count to a file. I implemented a very basic code but when the list is larger then it takes days to complete and sometimes shows memory error. The list size range between 3 and 1000. The code is as below.

```
for comb in itertools.combinations(my_list,3):
              combi_list.append(comb)

combi_list_new = list(set(combi_list))
print len(combi_list_new)    

mainlist_chunk = []
list_coupled_count_chunk = []

for comb in combi_list_new:
         if comb not in mainlist_chunk:
                    mainlist_chunk.append(comb)
                    temp_coupled = []
                    temp_coupled.append(comb)
                    temp_coupled.append(int(1))
                    list_coupled_count_chunk.append(temp_coupled)

         else:
                    for ind in range(len(mainlist_chunk)):
                        if mainlist_chunk[ind] == comb:
                            list_coupled_count_chunk[ind][1] = list_coupled_count_chunk[ind][1] + 1


with open("C:\\chunk_count.txt","ab") as bb:
                wd = csv.writer(bb,delimiter = "\t")
                wd.writerows(list_coupled_count_chunk)
                bb.close()
```

Can anyone help me with a faster implementation in python?

Comment: there are n over 3 ways to pick 3 out of n. with n = 1000, this is 1000 * 999 * 998 / 6 = 166,167,000. That's quite a lot.

Comment: I think your problem is combinatoric complexity. `itertools.combinations` explodes. You can reduce your memory consumption by using combinations as iterator, but given the many ways you cache and search, I don't see much room for improvement. You might have to rethink your approach.